# Rails 7 Flatpickr disable time and date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, flatpickr

Currently I am working on a booking app and I am trying to disable times based on bookings already created. However, I only see documentation to disable a whole day/range of days. Is it possible to do something like this? And if not, are there libraries out there that can handle this with Rails 7? Thank you!

flatpickr_controller.js

Currently supported:

```rb
 disable: [
        {
            from: "2023-10-10",
            to: "2023-10-10"
        },
       
    ]
```

My requirement:

```rb
 disable: [
        {
            from: "2023-10-10 1:00 PM",
            to: "2023-10-10 2:00 PM"
        },
       
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't think they have that feature yet, CMIIW

https://github.com/flatpickr/flatpickr/discussions/2841

Comment: Yeah seems like it. Do you know of any library that might include a feature like this? Seems like every library has some things that I need but not others and it makes it a bit cumbersome